# Roblox - attempt to call a nil value

Tags: roblox

When trying to create a code, that on FireServer with Specific Player chosen a GUI would've been cloned into their PlayerGui, But instead I get a nil value.

Code:

```
local Blinder = game.ReplicatedStorage.RCD.Blind


Blinder.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(player, PlayerToBlind)
    if not player:IsInGroup(7465879) then return false end;
    script.BL:Clone().Parent = PlayerToBlind:WaitForChild("PlayerGui")
    print("Done")
end)
```

Basically what I  try to reach is if my Admin Panel Remoteevent is fired, and a Target has been chosen, the Targeted Player will become a Cloned GUI into their PlayerGui

Any fix on this error?

Comment: Heyo, could you post the full error message?

Comment: `ServerScriptService.RCDHandler:6: attempt to call a nil value`

Answer (score 0):

The error message itself is telling you that you are calling a function that doesn't exist. This issue is caused by an object not being the type you expect.

Unfortunately, the message is pointing at a line that has a few function calls, so it's difficult to say what is causing the exact error. Either `script.BL` isn't an object with a `Clone()` function, or `PlayerToBlind` isn't an object with a `WaitForChild()` function.

If you can break the operations into a few different lines and add safety checks along the way, you can guarantee that your code is safe and being called properly.

```
local ReplicatedStorage = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
local Players = game:GetService("Players")
local Blinder = ReplicatedStorage.RCD.Blind
local BL = script.BL

Blinder.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(player, PlayerToBlind)
    -- check that the person calling Blinder:FireServer actually provided a PlayerToBlind
    assert(type(PlayerToBind) == "string", "Blinder expects PlayerToBind to be the name of a player")

    -- escape if the player is not in the appropriate group
    if not player:IsInGroup(7465879) then
        return
    end

    -- find the Player object based on the name provided from PlayerToBlind
    local blindedPlayer = Players:FindFirstChild(PlayerToBlind)
    if not blindedPlayer then
        warn("Could not find player named : ", PlayerToBlind)
        return
    end

    -- create a blinding UI on the other player
    local targetGui = blindedPlayer:WaitForChild("PlayerGui")
    local newBL = BL:Clone()
    newBL.Parent = targetGui

    print("Done")
end)
```

By adding asserts into your code, it won't stop your code from breaking, in fact it will force your code to break faster and in expected ways.

Comment: So, After trying to use this Script It still gives me
`ServerScriptService.RCDHandler:15: attempt to call a nil value`

Whenever clicking on the Error in the Output, it is going to
`newBL.Parent = PlayerToBlind:WaitForChild("PlayerGui")`

Video here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ToNXoIKcCWc&feature=youtu.be

Comment: Wait, I was making the assumption the `PlayerToBind` was a Player object. What object are you passing in when you call `Blinder:FireServer()`?

Comment: `Blinder:FireServer(InputUser.text)`

Basically the Input/Text that has been typen into the TextBox (Target Player)

Comment: Now it is giving me a warning
`Could not find player named :  Blind Player`

Comment: That's not a player's name

Comment: I fixed it, the Text has been grabbed from a TextButton instead of a TextBox

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been fixed,

I have been setting up the LocalScript wrong.

(I grabbed the Text from a TextButton, Instead of the TextBox)